# trying to understand $.inArray, or converting $scope to "controller As" syntax in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this should be a relatively simple one for you all, im trying to use a filter that I've found online in my Angular app, and trying to understand the $.inArray method in this JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/

I am familiar with $scope, but never have seen the $.inArray method and dont know how to convert this over to vm.key notation.

I would normally try and figure this out on my own but my project is due in a few hours and ive already pulled an all nighter, first time asking a question here, thanks to anyone who can help in advance.

ive converted it so far to this: http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/646/

html:
```

```
<div ng-app="fruit">
    <div ng-controller="FruitCtrl as vm">

        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.includeColour('Red')"/> Red</br/>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.includeColour('Orange')"/> Orange</br/>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.includeColour('Yellow')"/> Yellow</br/>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="f in fruit | filter:vm.colourFilter">
                {{f.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>

        Filter dump: {{colourIncludes}}
    </div>
</div>
```

```

and my js:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('fruit', []);

function FruitCtrl() {
        var vm = this;
    vm.fruit = [
        {'name': 'Apple', 'colour': 'Red'},
        {'name': 'Orange', 'colour': 'Orange'},
        {'name': 'Banana', 'colour': 'Yellow'}];

    vm.colourIncludes = [];

    vm.includeColour = function(colour) {
        var i = $.inArray(colour, vm.colourIncludes);
        if (i > -1) {
            vm.colourIncludes.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            vm.colourIncludes.push(colour);
        }
    }

    vm.colourFilter = function(fruit) {
        if (vm.colourIncludes.length > 0) {
            if ($.inArray(fruit.colour, vm.colourIncludes) < 0)
                return;
        }

        return fruit;
    }
}
```

```

but it doesnt seem to work quite right yet, nothing I try works, I know I have a lacking of fundamentals behind it but I only need this one last feature to work and Ill be done with my project so, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your Fiddle uses Angular 1.1 which predates "controller as" syntax. Use a new version of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You did not create controller.

Right code:

```
angular.module('fruit', [])
    .controller( 'FruitCtrl', FruitCtrl );
```

JsFiddle example:

```js
'use strict'

angular.module('fruit', [])
    .controller( 'FruitCtrl', FruitCtrl ); 

function FruitCtrl() {
        var vm = this;
    vm.fruit = [
        {'name': 'Apple', 'colour': 'Red'},
        {'name': 'Orange', 'colour': 'Orange'},
        {'name': 'Banana', 'colour': 'Yellow'}];

    vm.colors = {};

    vm.colourFilter = function(fruit) {
        console.log( fruit, vm.colors[fruit.colour] );
        return vm.colors[fruit.colour];
    }
    
    vm.selectedFruits = [];
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="fruit">
    <div ng-controller="FruitCtrl as vm">

        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.colors.Red"/> Red</br/>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.colors.Orange"/> Orange</br/>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.colors.Yellow"/> Yellow</br/>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="f in vm.fruit | filter:vm.colourFilter">
                {{f.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>

        Filter dump: {{vm.colors}}
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are right! i forgot.  However I just tried it now and it still didnt work, am i a complete dunce that I cant get this JSfiddle working?

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct, if you found it useful. Thanks.